# XSLT on XML with Namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am stuck trying to transform xml with namepsaces using xsl. Here are my files. As you can see, I am trying multiple xpath options in the xsl document. I get no errors, only a blank document. I have been researching for an hour without any luck. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

sample.xml:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample.xsl"?>
<POCollection xmlns:ns1="http://www.a.com/PurchaseOrder/1.0" xmlns="http://www.a.com/PurchaseOrder/1.0">
    <ns1:PurchaseOrder>
        <ns1:PurchaseOrderHeader>
            <ns1:OUAddressLine1>123 Test Street</ns1:OUAddressLine1>
        </ns1:PurchaseOrderHeader>
    </ns1:PurchaseOrder>
</POCollection>
```

sample.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://www.nsl.ns/" xmlns:d="http://www.default.ns/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/d:POCollection/ns1:PurchaseOrder/ns1:PurchaseOrderHeader/ns1:OUAddressLine1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:PurchaseOrder/ns1:PurchaseOrderHeader/ns1:OUAddressLine1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="/POCollection/ns1:PurchaseOrder/ns1:PurchaseOrderHeader/ns1:OUAddressLine1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="/POCollection/PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrderHeader/OUAddressLine1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="//OUAddressLine1" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POCollection` in sample.xml has default namespace `xmlns="http://www.amway.com/PurchaseOrder/1.0"`

So why you define `xmlns:d="http://www.default.ns/` in your XSLT?

```
<!-- in input xml is no element from "http://www.default.ns" namespace -->
<xsl:value-of select="/d:POCollection/ns1:PurchaseOrder/ns1:PurchaseOrderHeader/ns1:OUAddressLine1" />

<!-- Element ns1:PurchaseOrder is not document element (the outermost element) in input xml -->
<xsl:value-of select="/ns1:PurchaseOrder/ns1:PurchaseOrderHeader/ns1:OUAddressLine1" />

<!-- There is no element POCollection from null namespace in input xsml -->
<xsl:value-of select="/POCollection/ns1:PurchaseOrder/ns1:PurchaseOrderHeader/ns1:OUAddressLine1" />

<!-- dtto -->
<xsl:value-of select="/POCollection/PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrderHeader/OUAddressLine1" />

<!-- dtto -->
<xsl:value-of select="//OUAddressLine1" />
```

Edit: following should work

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:amw="http://www.amway.com/PurchaseOrder/1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/amw:POCollection/amw:PurchaseOrder/amw:PurchaseOrderHeader/amw:OUAddressLine1" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//amw:PurchaseOrder/amw:PurchaseOrderHeader/amw:OUAddressLine1" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/amw:POCollection/amw:PurchaseOrder/amw:PurchaseOrderHeader/amw:OUAddressLine1" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//amw:OUAddressLine1" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I was dismayed that you initially told me everything that was wrong, but not how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for that... I was writing faster than thinking :) The main point IMO is that prefix of namespace is not important (may differs in xml and xslt) but URI it is assignig to is crucial. There were absolutely different URIs in your sample.xslt than in sample.xml - therefore nothing has been found.

Answer (score 0):

The second one that I listed was almost right, excepting a typo where I excluded the top node. Here is what I ended up with.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://www.nsl.ns/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/ns1:POCollection">
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns1:OUAddressLine1" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```